# Append empty rows by subtracting 7 days from date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How can I create empty rows  from 7 days before 2016-01-01  going to  January 2015? I tried reindexing
df

```
     date         value
0 2016-01-01       4.0
1 2016-01-08       5.0
2 2016-01-15       1.0
```

Expected Output

```
       date       value
   2015-01-02      NaN
   ....
   2015-12-25      NaN
   2016-01-01      4.0
   2016-01-08      5.0
   2016-01-15      1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
```

And then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) by your minimal value and minimal index value with [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) for avoid lost original index values:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-02', df.index.min(), freq='7d').union(df.index)
df = df.reindex(rng)
```

---

```
print (df)
            value
2015-01-02    NaN
2015-01-09    NaN
2015-01-16    NaN
2015-01-23    NaN
2015-01-30    NaN
2015-02-06    NaN
2015-02-13    NaN
2015-02-20    NaN
2015-02-27    NaN
2015-03-06    NaN
2015-03-13    NaN
2015-03-20    NaN
2015-03-27    NaN
2015-04-03    NaN
2015-04-10    NaN
2015-04-17    NaN
2015-04-24    NaN
2015-05-01    NaN
2015-05-08    NaN
2015-05-15    NaN
2015-05-22    NaN
2015-05-29    NaN
2015-06-05    NaN
2015-06-12    NaN
2015-06-19    NaN
2015-06-26    NaN
2015-07-03    NaN
2015-07-10    NaN
2015-07-17    NaN
2015-07-24    NaN
2015-07-31    NaN
2015-08-07    NaN
2015-08-14    NaN
2015-08-21    NaN
2015-08-28    NaN
2015-09-04    NaN
2015-09-11    NaN
2015-09-18    NaN
2015-09-25    NaN
2015-10-02    NaN
2015-10-09    NaN
2015-10-16    NaN
2015-10-23    NaN
2015-10-30    NaN
2015-11-06    NaN
2015-11-13    NaN
2015-11-20    NaN
2015-11-27    NaN
2015-12-04    NaN
2015-12-11    NaN
2015-12-18    NaN
2015-12-25    NaN
2016-01-01    4.0
2016-01-08    5.0
2016-01-15    1.0
```

Comment: Sorry, just curious.  How do we know the date range start date is '2015-01-02' ?  That is, '2015-01-02' will fit into one of the 7d slots counting back from '2016-01-01' ?

Comment: @SeaBean - It count `pd.date_range` by freq=`7d`

Comment: Many thanks . Is there a general  way to replace empty values we've just added before 2016 to the value affiliated with last available date (in this case 2016-01-01)?

Comment: @asd - use `df.reindex(rng).bfill()`

Comment: What if counting back from '2016-01-01' the 7d slots the first day of 2015 could be '2015-01-01' or '2015-01-03'.  How do we know in advance ?

Comment: @SeaBean - I think (hope) pandas count it correctly.

Comment: I asked this question because we have to hardcode this start date into the first parameter of pd.date_range().  At that time, if we have not yet produce any results or pre-generate a list, we may not know what to hardcode for this parm then.  Anyway, it's fine if we can randomly gen a list and see the result if this range is a fixed range known in advance.

Comment: @SeaBean - ya, I think pandas create next minimal matched datetime here.

Comment: I see.  Appreciate much for the explanation.

Comment: I tried `rng = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), '2015-01-01', freq='-7d').union(df.index)` That is, reversing the parms of start date and end date and set `freq='-7d'` instead of 7d.  Here, `'2015-01-01'` is just set arbitrarily to the first date of January 2015.  As @jezrael said, pandas matched it correctly to set first entry as '2015-01-02' instead of '2015-01-01'.    In this way, I don't need to bother to guess wisely for a date in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to retain the index name, "date", when reindexing? I could add a new line at the end but was wondering if there's a built in way/option

Comment: @asd - You can use `df = df.reindex(rng.rename('Date'))`

Comment: Many thanks @jezrael. I've updated the question to a multi-index problem, only if you get time. I tried ```get_level_values``` but the reindexing wouldn't work because of duplicate dates in the index

Comment: @asd - Is possible post new question?

Comment: Sure, sorry, just did. I'll revert this question to how it was